# MySQL ORDER BY column ASC containing two words not correctly alphabetized

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to sort the following table:

**Table: People**

```
+---+----------------------+
|id |       Ethnicity      | 
+---+----------------------+
| 1 | 'Hispanic'           |
| 2 | 'Asian American'     | 
| 3 | 'White'              |
| 4 | 'African American'   | 
| 5 | 'American Indian'    | 
| 6 | 'Other'              |
+---+----------------------+
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ethnicity FROM People ORDER BY Ethnicity ASC
```

**Results**

This generates:

```
+----------------------+
|       Ethnicity      | 
+----------------------+
| 'American Indian'    |
| 'Asian American'     |
| 'African American'   |
| 'Hispanic'           |
| 'White'              |
| 'Other'              |
+----------------------+
```

The results I want to generate are:

```
+----------------------+
|       Ethnicity      | 
+----------------------+
| 'African American'   |
| 'American Indian'    |
| 'Asian American'     |
| 'Hispanic'           |
| 'Other'              |
| 'White'              |
+----------------------+
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What is the data type and character encoding of the Ethnicity column?

Comment: Data type is enum.  Character encoding is latin1_general_ci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data type is an enum, I believe it will order by the item's position (index) in the enum list, not the value of the enum string. Is "American Indian" the first item in your enum definition?